# Using Python variables in markdown block in Kaggle notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, kaggle

Kaggle notebooks are based on Jupiter notebooks, available to write code blocks in Python, R, or "Markdown text".
The option of formatting the text and make it human-reader-friendly is only in the Markdown blocks.

What I'm trying to do, is to include the value of a variable from a python code block (earlier in the notebook) into the text in the Markdown block.

Using such a value in a different code block is the normal approach in Kaggle notebooks, and is working well.

Looking in Python documentation and Kaggle-notebook help, it seems that there were over the year some formats to include those dynamic data in the Markdown block. Some mention "{{variable}}" format, others [variable], and more.

When nothing worked for me, I came into the option of adding Python-Markdown library (or Kernel?) into the notebook.
The problem is I don't know if this option available of Kaggle notebooks.

A notebook sample with un-successful try to include the Python variable is available here:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/offerl/exploring-real-time-transit-data-part-1
(The variable is in the last Markdown paragraph)

Any help would be appreciated.